# I can't get ads when I download my app from google play

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've added the Admob ad to our Android app. I'm getting Advertising from Android Studio. I receive ads when I manually install the APK file to the phone. However, I can't get ads when I upload the app to Google Play and download it from Google Play. I get error code 3 (ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL). I couldn't find the solution. PLEASE HELP !

android studio avd run img:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaH4H.png)

when I manually install the APK file to the phone:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw942.jpg)

When I download it from Google Play:
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPmiG.png)

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadAdmobBanner();
    AdmobBannerListener();


}

private void loadAdmobBanner() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
    mAdView_Banner = findViewById(R.id.adView_Banner_Main);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView_Banner.loadAd(adRequest);
}
private void AdmobBannerListener(){
    mAdView_Banner.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdImpression() {
            super.onAdImpression();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check the ids and wait for a while. And connect the app to admob later.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to admobs account. > Go to app > ad units> check if add units are active and are associated with advertiser.

Usually adMob will take time to do this job.

Comment: I checked my admob account. all ad units are active